# AngularJS2 : Getting 404 Not Found in the models folder even though file is there

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, angular

I have the following app structure:

[image: Project Structure]

I want my application where each page like "Create.cshtml" will

bootstrap(**Scripts/app/project/create/app.projects.create-boot.ts**) 
and 
load the application (**/app.projects.create.ts**).

I also have a models folder which will hold all my models and will be shared.

serviceline.js(**Scripts/models/serviceline.ts**)

app.projects.create-boot.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppProjectsCreateComponent} from './app.projects.create'
import {ServiceLine} from '../../../models/serviceline';
bootstrap(AppProjectsCreateComponent, [ServiceLine]);
```

app.projects.create.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ServiceLine} from '../../../models/serviceline';

@Component({
    selector: 'project-create',
    templateUrl: '../../appScripts/app/projects/create/app.projects.create.html'
})
export class AppProjectsCreateComponent {
    name = "max";
    serviceLines: ServiceLine[];
    constructor() {
        //this.serviceLines = [ new ServiceLine(1, "Name Test") ];
    }
}
```

serviceLine.ts

```
export class ServiceLine {
    ServiceLineId: number;
    Name: string

    constructor(serviceLineId: number, name: string) {
        this.ServiceLineId = serviceLineId;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@section head{
    <script src="~/lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/system.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/rx.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->    
}

@{
    <script>
        System.config({
            map: {
                appScripts: '../appScripts/app/projects/create'
            },
            packages: {
                appScripts: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });

        System.import('appScripts/app.projects.create-boot')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
}
<br />
<project-create></project-create>
```

Everything was loading find until I added ServiceLine[] in the app.projects.create.ts file.

Here is the error:
[image: Error]

What am I missing? Why can't Angular find the serviceLine.js.

Edit: Change the map field.

```
<script>
        System.config({
            map: {
                appScripts: '../appScripts' //Change Here
            },
            packages: {
                appScripts: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });

        System.import('appScripts/app/projects/create/app.projects.create-boot') //Change Here
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your service file isn't targetted with your SystemJS configuration because of the map block.

So SystemJS doesn't append the JS extension. I would remove the map block:

```
    <script>
        System.config({
            /* map: {
                appScripts: '../appScripts/app/projects/create'
            }, */
            packages: {
                appScripts: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });

        System.import('appScripts/app/projects/create/app.projects.create-boot')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

and update accordingly the path in your imports.

With this configuration the "model" will be token into account. Your configuration would only work if your "model" folder was under the "create" one.

Comment: Tried this but now its complaining about the boot.js file.
angular2-polyfills.js:127 GET http://localhost:51932/Projects/appScripts/app/projects/create/app.projects.create-boot.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is the path you specified in "System.import" is correct? I just see that there was a typo at this level in my answer... What is the error now?

Comment: I actually tried changing the map along with your suggestion, and I believe it is working. However, getting this now:  Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ServiceLine'(?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'ServiceLine' is decorated with Injectable.

Comment: Took out the ServiceLine Inject in the boot, and everything is up and running.

Comment: yeah.. using your example of path format in system.import, and setting the map as "../appScripts" did the trick.